# SQL Select Column 'Name' in 3 Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select

"I have 3 Tables which is Admin table,Studentinfo Table and Useraccount Table.
i want to join that 3 tables for my search engine. :(
im beginner in sql anyone can help me?"

```
SELECT Username,Name,Position,Status,ImageName FROM useraccount 
JOIN admin ON admin.username = useraccount.username 
JOIN studentinfo ON studentinfo.username = useraccount.username 
where Name Like '%Search%';

"That is my code but nothing happen."
```

Comment: Also, post table data and expected resultset

Comment: Which table has 'Name' key.

Use table name before field name eg. useraccount.Username, Username.Position

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql-server?

Comment: Im using MySql 
And all Table have 'Name' Field

Comment: could you please share name of tables having following fields - Username,Name,Position,Status,ImageName, other wise these fields will conflict with other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with multiple tables you would have to compensate for column name ambiguity as the same column name could be available in other joining tables and there is no way for the query execution engine to know which one you want returned.

You can easily fix this by adding an alias or table name to referenced column Name 
`TableAlias.ColumnName
( or )
TableName.ColumnName`

**Example:**

```
SELECT Col1
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 
    ON table1.Col1= table2.Col2
```

Will generate a Ambiguous column name error.

```
SELECT t1.Col1
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t1.Col1= t2.Col2
```

Or

```
SELECT table1.Col1
FROM table1
JOIN table2
    ON table1.Col1= table2.Col2
```

**The changes:**

1. Added the prefix `"t1" or "TableName"` to the requested column, so that the engine knows which table we want the data from
2. Added table aliases in the FROM / JOIN clauses to shorten the code

**Scenario Example:**

```
SELECT <TableName>.Username,
       <TableName>.Name,
       <TableName>.Position,
       <TableName>.Status,
       <TableName>.ImageName
FROM useraccount
    JOIN admin
    ON admin.username = useraccount.username
    JOIN studentinfo
    ON studentinfo.username = useraccount.username
WHERE <TableName>.Name LIKE '%Search%';
```

Comment: Happy Coding. Glad to be of help.